# Suggest how to translate Objective C pointer arithmetic into Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm writing a program in Swift, which has scrolling in it and I decided to use this code, which works pretty well, but it is in Objective C:
https://gist.github.com/mayoff/4187399

I've translated 95% of it except one method, namely:

```
- (void)createPathPoints
```

I incorporate Objective C with Swift, using `UIBezierPath+forEachElement.m`
and `UIBezierPath+forEachElement.h` and the bridge to Swift.

I'm having difficulties with this method because it uses a lot of pointer arithmetic, which is not present in Swift. So I wonder can somebody help me to translate this one method, or suggest another way how one can load points of the `BezierPath` into an array.

The github link also provides link to original question of Stack Overflow, if somebody needs it.

Thank You!

Comment: What is the error or problem that you are getting?
Try to implement and provide the error you encountered

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to break BezierPath into points and store them in the array in swift.

Comment: I don't see any pointer arithmetic in that code. Also, there is pointer arithmetic in Swift (via `UnsafePointer` and its friends). Which part is causing you trouble? If you already have `forEachElement` available, why are you trying to break up the path? It already does that for you.